# MySQL: Cross table Referencing (primary, master, name) for categories and subcategories?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table labeled categories where main catgory(parent column) contains 0 and where subcategory contains the ID of the parent category. I heard it is called Referencing. My question:  Do i have this table strucutred properly? Or is there a better way like implementing a traversal tree or similar method?

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`primary_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`master_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
)

INSERT INTO `categories` (`primary_id`, `master_id`, `name`) VALUES 
(1, '0', 'Games'),
(2, '0', 'Technology'),
(3, '0', 'Science'),
(4, '0', 'Pop Culture'),
(5, '0', 'Jobs/Services'),
(6, '0', 'Blogs'), 
(7, '1', 'Computer'),
(8, '1', 'Game Console'),
(9, '2', 'Cellphone'),
(10, '2', 'Audio/Video/Photos'),
(11, '2', 'Laptop'),
(12, '2', 'Others >'),
(13, '3', 'Human Body'),
(14, '3', 'Ocean Life'),
(15, '3', 'Plant Life'),
(16, '3', 'Animal Life'),
(17, '4', 'Artist'),
(18, '4', 'Upcoming'),
(19, '5', 'Jobs'),
(20, '5', 'Tutoring'),
(21, '5', 'Seminars'),
(22, '5', 'Haircuts'),
(23, '9', 'Iphone'),
(24, '9', 'Android'),
(25, '9', 'Windows Mobile'),
(26, '11', 'Toshiba'),
(27, '11', 'HP'),
(28, '11', 'Apple'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the InnoDB engine, you can enforce referential integrity for your tables. That way, you can make sure you never insert a category which does not have matching parent id, cascade delete child categories when you delete the parent, etc. Change your create statement to:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`primary_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`master_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`),
KEY `fk_master_id1` (`master_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_master_id1` FOREIGN KEY (`master_id`) REFERENCES `master` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

While this strategy works sufficiently well for most cases, you might also want to look at other strategies for implementing tree-like structures and the challenges that come with querying them effectively. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800334/473637) answer on SO for more information on alternative designs for storing tree-like structures in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you! I will follow your advice.

Comment: how come when i run the query i get the error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 7"

Comment: try it now. make sure you edit the query to match your actual column names of the master table.